# JSON-LD Frame to display on children in parent child relationship

Tags: json-ld

I am trying to get an understanding of JSON-LD framing. The Library example in the JSON-LD Playground is very similar to what I need but with the way contains is setup, it seems like 1 library can only have 1 book that can only have 1 chapter. How can this be extended to support multiple items.

Here is a gist I created for the playground. I would like a blog to contain multiple comments, each comment includes a ref to the blog as a parent. I'd like the frame to then output the blog and all associated comments. At the moment the frame lists the blog for each comment. What should the frame syntax be?

http://json-ld.org/playground/#/gist/21d76e1bd113a28d96937d6672684e83

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reverse property support has neither been implemented not spec'ed yet (there's an open issue for that: https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues/311). So, unless you change the input document to point from the blog post to comments, you can't write a frame that outputs a blog and links to the associated comments at the moment.